# Custom view click listener cover all the screen instead of just the view

Tags: android, canvas, onclick, listener, android-custom-view

I've created a class that extends View in order to draw it myself, in a specific position.
I have overriden the `onDraw` method:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {     
    super.onDraw(canvas);   
    canvas.drawBitmap(pic, x, y, null);
}
```

When I set a click listener and add the view to a layout, the event fires even when I'm not clicking on the view's area. 
I tried setting the layout parameters to wrap content with no help, tried delete "`super.onDraw`" didn't help too.
If I'm doing the same actions with a built in view (like button or image view), it's not happening.

What's the problem? Am I doing something wrong?

More code:

```
public class FlowingPicture extends View {

    private float x,y;
    private Bitmap pic;
    private int screenWidth;
    private int screenHeight;

    public FlowingPicture(Context context, Bitmap pic, int x, int y, WindowManager screenSize) {
        super(context);
        screenHeight = screenSize.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        screenWidth = screenSize.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        this.pic = pic;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void move(float x, float y){
        this.x += x;
        if(this.x > screenWidth)
            this.x = -(this.pic.getWidth());
        this.y += y;
        this.postInvalidate();
    }

    public float getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public float getY(){
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {     
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(pic, x, y, null);
    }
}
```

The part of the code that creates the view:

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++){
    Bitmap b = arr.get(i).getFlowProfilePic();
    int x, y;
    do{
        y = rand.nextInt(screenHeight - b.getHeight() - 30);
        x = rand.nextInt(screenWidth);
    }
    while (!checkPoint(x, b.getWidth(), y, b.getHeight()));
    takenPoints.add(new Point(x, y));
    FlowingPicture fp = new FlowingPicture(FlowingFeeds.this, b, -(x + b.getWidth()), y, getWindowManager());
    fp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(FlowingFeeds.this, "I'm working!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    fp.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    flowingObjectsList.add(fp);
}
parseHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

The parseHandler adding the views to the layout:

```
for(FlowingPicture fp : flowingObjectsList){                
    layout.addView(fp);
}
flow = new Thread(FlowingFeeds.this);
flow.start();
```

And the last part:

```
layout = new FrameLayout(this);
layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: please show more code, as well as getting your acceptance rating up (go back and accept past answers)

Comment: is the view covering the entire screen, A good way to test it is setBackgroundColor to a transparent value and see how the view has laid out on the screen.

Comment: I would recommend looking into using XML resources for this.  I find it much cleaner.

Comment: owen gerig, I did as you've asked. 
Prakash Nadar, I did it, saw the picture on a black background, which means the view not covering the screen but the "listener" somehow do.

Comment: @Elad92 What exactly should be listening for taps and clicks?

Comment: @MikeD, just the image itself.

Comment: I did some research and found out that I need to override the onMeasure method. Tried to understand how to do it, but with no success. Does someone know how should I override it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I didn't solved it, but I think I know what the problem was.
Because I'm moving the view all across the screen, it gave the view a space in the size fo the screen.
So I just add a touch listener to the layout that the views are on, that take the x and y of the touch and check if this touch is on a some view.
Not the most elegant solution, but I did my best!

Thanks for everyone who tried to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `super.onDraw(canvas)` last in your method, but that may or may not get your where you want to go.

Hard to tell what your are doing wrong, but have you tried declaring BitmapField in your layout.  Unless there is more that needs to be shown, it looks like all your are doing a drawing an image to the screen.

Also in your `main.xml`, you can create what you need inside a `RelativeLayout`, and include `TextFields`, `BitmapFields`, and what ever other fields you need, that way, you won't have to worry about `onDraw()`.

The beauty of using the XML resources is there is a property `android:onClick="someMethod"`.  In the activity, you would then need a method:

```
public void someMethod( View view ) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

This way, there is no need to mess around with listeners.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I created this class for some reason.
I'm need an image to move on the screen and to be clickable at the same time. Unfortunately using android animation moving only the "graphics" of the view and not the view itself so the listener won't fire when the animated picture is being clicked.

Comment: @Elad92 you could apply the animation to whatever contains the image, but the main thread will probably get blocked until the animation is finished.